# Android - Recycler View with Grid Layout item span different rows and columns

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-gridlayout, gridlayoutmanager

I need to implement several views in the same recycler view, with different width and height size, take a look at this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN1en.png)

Sometimes I will need to paint a item that takes two colums, as the first item in the image, I already can do this with this:

```
 layoutManager.spanSizeLookup = object : SpanSizeLookup() {
        override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
            return if (twoColumns.contains(position)) 2 else 1
        }
    }
```

But I also have to do something like the item 6, that takes two rows and one column and currently I cannot do that, I tried with this [library](https://github.com/jmartinesp/SpannedGridLayoutManager), and also with FlexboxLayoutManager, and I can't achieve that.

Is there another layout manager that fit better to my approach, or any library?

Comment: You can use `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`, but you will still need to calculate and set the height manually for items to take its place as in the image.

Comment: Found any solution ??